# Запуск проекта на iphone 3g в среде xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone

Суть вопроса следующая. Есть джейлбрейкнутый iphone 3g на 4.2.1. При попытках запустить на нём свой проект - Xcode 4.3 пишет, что приложение успешно запущено, и сразу же - приложение остановлено. Реакции устройства - никакой. С сертификатами и аккаунтом разработчика всё в порядке, для xcode были загружены пакеты Device Debugging Support 4.0-4.1 (4.2 почему-то не оказалось в списке, далее шёл сразу 4.3), в настройках билда дописана архитектура armv6, iOS Deployment Target - 4.2. Что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настройках проекта и таргета в Architectures выберите Other вместо armv7, а потом добавьте новый пункт armv6 и выберите его вместо armv7.
Вроде бы проделать надо и в настройках проекта, и в настройках таргета.

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись, но к сожалению, не помогло.